# How to configure Django application deployed with Gunicorn with a front NGINX server, through docker compose?

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am finding difficulty in understanding the mistake in the following setup which attempts to serve a django-gunicorn application server with nginx. (Am not yet concentrating on static assets)

### Docker compose file

```
# Mentioning which format of dockerfile
version: "3.9"
# services or nicknamed the container
services:
  # web service for the web
  web:
    build: .
    # Add additional commands for webpack to 'watch for changes and bundle it to production'
    command: gunicorn --bind unix:/run_socket/gunicorn.sock StockWhiz.wsgi:application
    # Below command for using gunicorn to serve.
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./stockwhiz-web
        target: /code
      - type: bind
        source: ./run_socket
        target: /run_socket
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=StockWhiz.settings.local"

  db:
    image: postgres:14-bullseye
    #
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    # unsure of what this environment means.
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./run_socket:/run_socket
      - ./config/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
# Volumes set up
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

### NGINX config

```
# Note in our docker compose it's typically located at etc/nginx/conf.d/
# Which are automatically copied on to the nginx.conf file at etc/nginx
upstream gunicorn_application {
    server unix:/run_socket/gunicorn.sock;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.stockwhiz.in;
    error_log stderr warn;
    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass gunicorn_application;
    }
}
```

### Logs

Some of the logs from the docker compose are as below. I also have a 502, gateway error at `http://localhost`

```
stockwhizfullfiles-web-1    | [2022-12-09 06:05:27 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:63)
stockwhizfullfiles-nginx-1  | 2022/12/09 06:05:27 [error] 38#38: *25 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: www.stockwhiz.in, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run_socket/gunicorn.sock:", host: "localhost"
stockwhizfullfiles-nginx-1  | 172.25.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2022:06:05:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/108.0.1462.42" "-"
stockwhizfullfiles-web-1    | [2022-12-09 06:05:27 +0000] [63] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 63)
stockwhizfullfiles-web-1    | [2022-12-09 06:05:27 +0000] [64] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 64
stockwhizfullfiles-nginx-1  | 2022/12/09 06:05:58 [error] 38#38: *25 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: www.stockwhiz.in, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run_socket/gunicorn.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"       
stockwhizfullfiles-web-1    | [2022-12-09 06:05:58 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:64)
stockwhizfullfiles-nginx-1  | 172.25.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2022:06:05:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/108.0.1462.42" "-"
stockwhizfullfiles-web-1    | [2022-12-09 06:05:58 +0000] [64] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 64)
stockwhizfullfiles-web-1    | [2022-12-09 06:05:58 +0000] [79] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 79
```

Comment: Might help you :- https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, It has helped me get the site working. 
But at the same time I would like to use a sock file while serving the site.

Comment: Is it not working? In above blog he is passing proxy to localhost address in docker so no need of sock file.

Comment: Pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had quite a few problems on my end:

Problems;

- Edge, Firefox, and Chrome were redirected towards an `https://` protocol thanks to a carelessness in their respective settings and caches.
- An unfortunate link to the wrong settings file during one of the trials caused the caching in the browsers.
- Insufficient understanding of the Nginx configuration

I worked through the above problems by restarting with the default `runserver` commands and solving them at appropriate locations.

I also gave a sufficient read of the Nginx documentation and the book below which helped me understand Nginx config locations.

> Nginx HTTP Server: adopt Nginx for your web applications to make the most of your infrastructure and serve pages faster than ever

---

### Serving the site

Initially I tried serving the site through a sock file. I came across [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) tutorial (also mentioned by @AjayK) which does so by a simple proxy server in Nginx.

Thus modifying the nginx config file as below while exposing the `8000` port on the `web` service will help serve the application.

```
upstream gunicorn_app{
    server web:8000;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost ;
    error_log stderr warn;
    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

*Note*:

- A *compose application* includes a DNS network where one can refer to *services* through their respective names.